# XMLTABLE, XQUERY - expected singleton sequence

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltable

XML:

```
<import>
    <persons>
        <person>
            <pm>57924160</pm>
            <date_from>2018-05-01</date_from>
            <info>
                <set>
                    <indflag>0</indflag>
                </set>
                <items>
                    <item>
                        <symbol>a</symbol>
                        <date>2018-05-02</date>
                        <cost>190</cost>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <symbol>b</symbol>
                        <date>2018-05-02</date>
                        <cost>130</cost>
                    </item>
                </items>
            </info>
        </person>
    </persons>
    <persons>
        <person>
            <pm>57924160</pm>
            <date_from>2018-05-01</date_from>
            <info>
                <set>
                    <indflag>0</indflag>
                </set>
                <items>
                    <item>
                        <symbol>a</symbol>
                        <date>2018-05-02</date>
                        <cost>190</cost>
                    </item>
                    <item>
                        <symbol>b</symbol>
                        <date>2018-05-02</date>
                        <cost>130</cost>
                    </item>
                </items>
            </info>
        </person>
    </persons>
</import>
```

And im reading this xml in loop via:

```
 SELECT xt.*
   FROM  XMLTABLE(
         '//import/persons/person'
         PASSING xmltype('above_xml')
         COLUMNS 
           pm        VARCHAR2(4)  PATH 'pm',
           indflag   VARCHAR2(10) PATH 'info/set/indflag'
         ) xt;
```

but if i add another column

```
item      varchar2(10) PATH 'info/items/item/symbol'
```

it gives me ORA, because xmltable expecting 1 value per person, and there are two items on person.

Of course i could handle it in pl/sql like get full person node, select all items etc., but i wonder if this could be done in single query, to get output like:

```
PM    INDFLAG  item
5792    0        a
5792    0        b
```

Comment: You have multiple items/symbols per person, so wouldn't you expect four rows in your result set now?

Answer (score 1):

You could either use two levels of XMLTable:

```
select x1.pm, x1.indflag, x2.item
  from  xmltable(
         '//import/persons/person'
         passing xmltype('above_xml')
         columns 
           pm        varchar2(4)  path 'pm',
           indflag   varchar2(10) path 'info/set/indflag',
           items     xmltype      path 'info/items'
         ) x1
  cross join  xmltable(
         '/items/item'
         passing x1.items
         columns 
           item      varchar2(10) PATH 'symbol'
         ) x2;

PM   INDFLAG    ITEM      
---- ---------- ----------
5792 0          a         
5792 0          b         
5792 0          a         
5792 0          b
```

or less flexibly but OK here with only one child collection, start at item level and work back up for the higher level node data:

```
select xt.pm, xt.indflag, xt.item
  from  xmltable(
         '//import/persons/person/info/items/item'
         passing xmltype('above_xml')
         columns 
           pm        varchar2(4)  path './../../../pm',
           indflag   varchar2(10) path './../../set/indflag',
           item      varchar2(10) PATH 'symbol'
         ) xt;

PM   INDFLAG    ITEM      
---- ---------- ----------
5792 0          a         
5792 0          b         
5792 0          a         
5792 0          b
```

(The second approach doesn't seem to work in [11.2.0.2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c18980838b9da3064d3d106b5ac3b65c) which must be a bug; it does work in 11.2.0.4, and higher versions including [18c](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e4e9641a904d86b81da4d14aaba1d90e).)